# how i can to call directive ngxPrint from code (angular 7)

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have  a two buttons. First button create my data for print to .pdf, and second button setup ngxPrint

```
<button class="report-btn" [class.btn-disabled]="!settingsReport.fromTo || isIncorrectFile" type="button" (click)="performReport()" [translate]="'report.btn'"></button>


<button class="report-btn"
                            [class.btn-disabled]="!reportGenerated"
                            [useExistingCss]="true"
                            ngxPrint
                            printSectionId="report-print"
                            type="button"
                            [translate]="'report.btn-print'"></button>
```

I want combine buttons, and in the end have one button.

Unfortunately when I copy (click) event from first buttons to second, i have error.
and my function is not called when clicked

```
<button class="report-btn"
                            (click)="performReport()"
                            [class.btn-disabled]="!settingsReport.fromTo || isIncorrectFile"
                            type="button"
                            [translate]="'report.btn-print'"
                            [useExistingCss]="true"
                            printSectionId="report-print"
                            ngxPrint
                    ></button>
```

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
    at NgxPrintDirective.push.../node_modules/ngx-print/fesm5/ngx-print.js.NgxPrintDirective.print (ngx-print.js:197)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ReportsComponent.html:132)
    at handleEvent (core.js:23107)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:24177)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:23904)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:20556)
    at core.js:21003
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:993)
    at ZoneDelegate.push.../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)
```

so, I think, I need to call directive from my .component.ts, but i don't know how do it

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did, might be helpful

made the button with ngxPrint directive hidden & added a ViewChild selector to it.

in Template,

```
<!--- This is hidden using CSS ----->
<button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-sm d-none"
    [useExistingCss]="true"
    printSectionId="print-section"
    #printBtn
    ngxPrint
> 
 Print
</button>

<!-- This button will trigger click event on the hidden button -->
<button (click)="saveAndPrint()"> Print </button>
```

In component,

```
@ViewChild('printBtn') printBtn: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
```

Then added another button with click event like follows,

```
saveAndPrint() {
    this.saveToServer();
    let el: HTMLElement = this.printBtn.nativeElement;
    el.click();
}
```